# What happens when try with resources throws an exception along with an exception when closing the resources automatically

Tags: java, exception, java-8, try-with-resources

Imagine a situation where, an exception occurs in try with resources block. It will call the close method to close the resources. What happens if close method also throws an exception. Which exception is thrown.?

Comment: [It’s all in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html#suppressed-exceptions). Even [the tag info of `[try-with-resources]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/try-with-resources/info) which you used in your question explains it…

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: Both! The first one is just a bit more prominent.

First your inner exception will be thrown. Then the close() method of the Closeable will be called and if that one does also throw its exception, it will be *suppressed* by the first one. You can see that in the stack trace.

Test code:

```
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (Test test = new Test()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("RuntimeException");
        }
    }

    private static class Test implements Closeable {
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("IOException");
        }
    }
}
```

Console log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: RuntimeException
    at DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:15)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: IOException
        at DemoApplication$Test.close(DemoApplication.java:22)
        at DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:16)
```

If you like to, you can get the suppressed exception with `exception.getSuppressed()`.

Comment: Your description has it the wrong way around, it is the **second** exception (i.e. the one thrown by the `close` operation) that will be suppressed.  As shown by the stacktrace!

Comment: The description given was right as it is said that the Exception thrown by the close method is suppressed.

Comment: What happens if ONLY close() throws an exception?